# Button disappears but the other column members of the row remains visible in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

I am writing a code to make sure that if the translate button is pressed a new row appears but all the row members except string text are visible..Now i have written the code but it only makes the button disappear and all the members are still visible.
[image: Now this is the initial datagridview]

This is the view after the button is pressed..
[image]

Now the button is invisible but all the other members are still visible.this is the code i have tried..

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    bool ce = false;
    bool check = true;
    Column_handling();
    DataGridViewTextBoxCell c = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    if(!(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = false;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 10)
        {
            if((Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) == Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].Cells[0].Value)) && (Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value) == Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].Cells[1].Value)))
            {
                ce = true;
            }
            if(!ce)
            {
                DataRow dt = datarows.NewRow();
                dt[0] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                dt[1] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                dt[2] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                dt[3] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                dt[4] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                dt[5] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                dt[6] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                dt[7] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                dt[8] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                dt[9] = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                datarows.Rows.InsertAt(dt, e.RowIndex + 1);
                var row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1];
                DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.Columns[2];
                DataGridViewCell cella = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cella.Style.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
                column.CellTemplate = cella;
                var cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell.Value = string.Empty;
                var cell1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell1.Value = string.Empty;
                var cell2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell2.Value = string.Empty;
                var cell3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell3.Value = string.Empty;
                var cell4 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell4.Value = string.Empty;
                var cell5 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell5.Value = string.Empty;
                var cell6 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell6.Value = string.Empty;
                var cell7 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell7.Value = string.Empty;
                var cell8 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell8.Value = string.Empty;
                var cell9 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell9.Value = string.Empty;
                var cell10 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell10.Value = string.Empty;
                row.Cells[10] = cell;//the button column
                row.Cells[0] = cell2;
                row.Cells[1] = cell3;
                row.Cells[3] = cell4;
                row.Cells[4] = cell5;
                row.Cells[5] = cell6;
                row.Cells[6] = cell7;
                row.Cells[7] = cell8;
                row.Cells[8] = cell9;
                row.Cells[9] = cell10;
                cell.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
            else if (!cao)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].Visible = true;
                var row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1];
                var cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell.Value = string.Empty;
                row.Cells[10] = cell;
                cell.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
                cao = true;
            }
            else if (ce)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].Visible = false;
                var row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1];
                var cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                cell.Value = string.Empty;
                row.Cells[10] = cell;
                cell.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
                cao= false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run under the debugger, with breakpoints on the lines you expect to be called?  Also, after hitting a breakpoint, have you examined the values of local variables, to make sure everything is getting set the way you expect? While it is good to give the whole block of code as you have, it would also be good if you pointed out some specific lines. E.g. "Here is the line that I thought would hide the other controls. I put a breakpoint on it, and it is being reached. And I confirmed that ...Visible does get set to False. As you see, I then call Refresh()" Why is it still visible?

Comment: And for testing GUI like this, breakpoints might interfere (the back-and-forth to debugger changes behavior). In that case, use Debug.Writeline in several places, to confirm what is happening internally. IN PARTICULAR, put Writeline anywhere in code that could UNDO the result you seek. A subtle type of bug is where what you want happens, but elsewhere in your code then undoes the result. FOr example, forcing a change to a control may cause a handler for that control to fire, resulting in a cascade of changes. Your job as a debugger, is to capture enough info to know what is happening inside.